# Type coercion bug in IE8 RegExp.exec()?

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I don't know if this is a know problem in IE8, but I can't really find any info on it.

```
// The regex can vary but has to have a non-matching group defined:
var re = /^(\s)?[\d]+$/i;
// We call it with a string...
re.exec("2");
// We call it with a number...
re.exec(2);
```

Firefox and Chrome (can't try it in Opera right now) have no problem with either calls. But on IE8 the second call fails with an "Object does not support that property or method".

Is this a known bug or something?

Comment: @works great on all of my browsers (+ie8) on my computer. ;)

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the second invocation of the regexp that fails? Have you tried it without the re.exec("2"); row? Does it fail?

Comment: @jishi yes.

@Caspar Kleijne Mmm... I'll have to take a deeper look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same issues in an Ext JS 4 application. Lots of things were failing as Ext JS appears to pass numbers in the exec() method at times. The issue turned out to be a third party library SyntaxHighlighter. Removing this reverted the default IE8 behavior and re.exec(2); worked.

I'd suggest cutting down the external JS that you include in your app until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Since exec takes a string I would make sure you are passing a string.  By passing a number in I would say you are trying to count on grey areas of the way browsers implement javascript.